# Fill remaining height with relative div

Tags: html, css

I have three div

```
div.main = encloses two child div
div.head = uses about 10%~20% of div.main height
div.body = uses about 80%~90% of div.main height
```

I want `div.body` to fill the remaining height space left after allocating `div.head`'s height.

I would like to do this with `position: relative;` as much as possible.

I am using percent values for the height and width and not pixels as screen resolutions may vary. I want it to resize itself automatically depending on the screen resolution of who may see it.

I noticed that if I use pixel values it works but not for percent.

Comment: Provide the code? What have you tried? Link to JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I have created a **main div** with color red(just to divide it), and the **2 divs** inside it, one head and one body with color yellow and green respectively.
I hope this is what you want -

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>try</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .main {
            position: relative;
            height:100%; 
            width:100%;
            border:5px solid black;
            background-color: red;
        }
        .head{
            position: relative;
            height:20%;
            width:100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .body{
            position: relative;
            height:80%;
            width:100%;
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main"> //main div having height & width 100%
        <div class="head"> //head with color yellow of 20%
        </div>
        <div class="body"> //head with color yellow of 80%
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position relative won't help you here..it doesn't size things by itself nor is it flexible as you seem to think.

I can think of a couple of way to do this (there may be others).

**Table Display**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  height: 250px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-table;
  /* usually just "table"...this is just to put the two tables side by side */
  margin: 25px;
}

header {
  display: table-row;
  background: lightblue;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}

.body {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, sed?</p>
  </header>
  <div class="body ">I'm the body</div>
</main>

<main>
  <header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique porro sunt placeat incidunt, quo vero. Assumenda deserunt excepturi fugit incidunt?</p>
  </header>
  <div class="body ">I'm the body</div>
</main>
```

**Flexbox**

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  height: 250px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-flex;
  /* usually just "flex" ....this is to put the elements side by side */
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

header {
  
  background: lightblue;
  border-bottom:1px solid red;
}

.body {
  flex:1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, sed?</p>
  </header>
  <div class="body"></div>
</main>

<main>
  <header><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique porro sunt placeat incidunt, quo vero. Assumenda deserunt excepturi fugit incidunt?</p>
  </header>
  <div class="body "></div>
</main>
```